# Script works on PyCharm but not in terminal

Tags: python

I am working on some API script in Python, it takes one argument and returns JSON. I am using BrawlStats library (https://github.com/SharpBit/brawlstats). It works very well in PyCharm but doesn't work in terminal, I have no idea why, I tried few suggestions like running "pip install" in script directory but it still doesn't help. I ma trying to run the script using PHP but it returns the same error as terminal: https://gyazo.com/afac3d7c7e50b4c4925ec767dc5457b2 + https://gyazo.com/5a55668e5e4cd005a64dd5c702043b98. Help would be really appreciated, I am stuck and I don't know how to fix it :/

Code:

```
import brawlstats
import json
import sys
client = brawlstats.Client("***")

def OMEGA(LUL):
    player = client.get_profile(LUL)

    xxDD = {
        "tag": player.tag,
        "name": player.name,
        "avatar": player.avatar_url,
        "trophies": player.trophies,
        "victories": player.victories,
        "level": player.exp_level
    }

    print(json.dumps(xxDD))
    return json.dumps(xxDD)

print(sys.argv[1])
OMEGA(sys.argv[1])
```

and here is error when I run it using PHP/terminal:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xampp/htdocs/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    OMEGA(sys.argv[1])
  File "C:/xampp/htdocs/main.py", line 8, in OMEGA
    player = client.get_profile(LUL)
  File "C:\Users\Krzysztof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\brawlstats\core.py", line 147, in get_profile
    data, resp = self._get(self.api.profile + '/' + tag)
  File "C:\Users\Krzysztof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\brawlstats\core.py", line 124, in _get
    with self.session.get(url, timeout=self.timeout, headers=self.headers) as resp:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Last thing, here is output when I run it using PyCharm:

```
{"tag": "CP0GU982", "name": "flick", "avatar": "https://fourjr.github.io/bs-assets/player_icons/28000000.png", "trophies": 6, "victories": 1, "level": 1}
```

Comment: Please add the code and error messages as text. Images cannot be parsed well by internal and external search engines.

Comment: Done @MaximilianPeters

Comment: I suspect your installed system version of python does not match pycharm installed version (which is a 3.6). Pycharm installs its own python and virtualenv locally.

Comment: "I'm trying to run the script using PHP"? Did you mean Python or am I missing something? I'm guessing your global Python isn't the same as the one used in Pycharm and/or you have differing packages in your virtualenv compared to your globally installed ones

Comment: Thank you for answers @ArthurHavlicek and, I have 3.62 Python installed and 3.6 in PyCharm virtualenv, there is only one package needed (the BrawlStars one), how can I fix it some easy way? Appreciate help

Comment: I will try to download the newest python 3.72 and try to install all from terminal

Comment: I love you guys, it works now!